# How to create two nested for loops in a single line in Julia

Tags: julia

I have seen it a few times where someone has a situation where they want to put two for loops on the same line nested in one another.

Just to confirm, is this possible in Julia and if so what does it look like? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some pseudo code which describes the double loop you have in mind?

Comment: Could be anything but seems most relevant for looping a 2-D array!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Correct, Julia allows you to tersely express nested [`for` loops](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-loops-1).

As an example, consider filling in a 3x3 matrix in column order:

```
julia> xs = zeros(3,3)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> let a = 1
           for j in 1:3, i in 1:3
               xs[i,j] = a
               a += 1
           end
       end

julia> xs
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  4.0  7.0
 2.0  5.0  8.0
 3.0  6.0  9.0
```

The above loop is equivalent to this more verbose version:

```
julia> let a = 1
           for j in 1:3
               for i in 1:3
                   xs[i,j] = a
                   a += 1
               end
           end
       end
```

This syntax is even supported for higher dimensions(!):

```
julia> for k in 1:3, j in 1:3, i in 1:3
           @show (i, j, k)
       end
```

Comment: Even more compact: list comprehension with nested conditions